# Counting backwards

Tags: counters

The following produces a counter that counts in increasing arabic numerals.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{myCounter}
  \addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
  \themyCounter
  \addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
  \themyCounter
  \addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
  \themyCounter
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted in the comments, one can have LaTeX count backwards with `\addtocounter{myCounter}{-1}`

[image]

but this has the disadvantage that you need to manually specify the starting value, n. That seems like a nuisance because if you want to add some additional items to the list then you also have to remember to update n.

Is there a way to have a custom latex counter count backwards *without* having to manually specify the value of n?

Comment: `\addtocounter{myCounter}{-1}`? Wait, i don't understand the question. You have to give LaTeX some point to start with.

Comment: You write `-1`, but in order to start from some number, you need to give *n*.

Comment: Do you know the `etaremune` package? Maybe it alread solves your problem. There are several threads on the site about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example lets increment the counter `myCounter` the usual way starting with 0, 1, 2. The latest value of the counter is stored in a `zref` label `LastPage` after the last page is shipped out. Then the appearance of the counter, `\themyCounter` is redefined to show the desired value by subtracting the actual value from the latest value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\newcounter{myCounter}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{myCounter}{\the\value{myCounter}}
\zref@addprop{LastPage}{myCounter}
\newcommand*{\myCounterLast}{%
  \zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{myCounter}{0}%
}
\renewcommand*{\themyCounter}{%
  \@arabic{\numexpr\myCounterLast+1-\value{myCounter}\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{myCounter}
\themyCounter
\stepcounter{myCounter}
\themyCounter
\stepcounter{myCounter}
\themyCounter 
\end{document}
```

In the first run, the label is written but not yet known, the latest value is assumed to be zero:

> [image: First run]

The next run shows the correct result:

> [image: Second run]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `totcount` package to grab the final value of a counter and use that to set your starting value.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{myCounter}
\newcounter{myDcounter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{myDcounter}{\totvalue{myCounter}}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{1}

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
\addtocounter{myDcounter}{-1}
Up \themyCounter\ and down
\themyDcounter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't understand the stipulation that one doesn't know the starting value of the counter. At any rate, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution that counts down from `n` (where `n` is set to `10`) to `1` in steps of `-1`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{ for i = 10, 1, -1 do tex.sprint(i.." ") end }
\end{document}
```